# Trouble with derived attribute creation in table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello all I am trying to create a table column named age which calculates the current age of that record by using the Birthdate column . The problem is it gives a error specifying that 'AS' is not valid in that position. I've tried looking at other similar questions but no success. Here is my code so far:

```
 CREATE TABLE test1 (
    name varchar(20),
    sex char(1),
    Birthdate datetime,
    age as TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Birthdate, CURDATE()) AS age ,
    SSN varchar(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (SSN) references Lab6T1_janesj(SSN),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Parent PRIMARY KEY (SSN,name)
 )
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation. You are likely looking for the `DEFAULT ` which set a column value and to be honest you would still need to test if you can use that function on the default value: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: Also post in your question the exact error message you are receiving back.

Comment: that will never work as the curdate is not deterministic

Answer (score 1):

The column name must follow a data type, the expression after `AS` has to be in `()` and you have one `AS age` at the end to many. So syntactically

```
...
age integer AS (timestampdiff(year, birthdate, curdate())),
...
```

would be right.

But `curdate()` cannot be used in a generated column. You might omit the column in the table and go with an additional view instead.

```
CREATE VIEW test1_with_age
AS
SELECT t.*,
       timestampdiff(year, t.birthdate, curdate()) AS age
       FROM test1 t;
```

Comment: Would there be anyway to have the view show up as a column when I do the command select * from test1;   ?

Comment: @Janes: If you named the table differently and the view `test1`.